# Dotted path in Django's INSTALLED_APPS fails to import

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, import

I have a django project of the canonical form:

```
.
├── app1/
├── app2/
├── ...
├── project/
└── manage.py
```

With all the additional folders that have started to add up that are not apps (e.g. docs) it's getting harder to keep it organized, so I have decided to make like so:

```
.
├── modules/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app1/
│   └── app2/
├── project/
└── manage.py
```

However, I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to reference the apps in my settings.py INSTALLED_APPS. Changing

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'app1.apps.App1Config'   -->   'modules.app1.apps.App1Config'
    'app2.apps.App2Config'   -->   'modules.app2.apps.App1Config'
]
```

will yield the cryptic traceback on ./manage.py runserver (/path/to/venv/ for brevity)

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 113, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
        app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 142, in create
        app_module = import_module(app_name)
      File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "", line 986, in _gcd_import
      File "", line 969, in _find_and_load
      File "", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ImportError: No module named 'app1'
```

Strangely enough, if I remove them from INSTALLED_APPS, the project will (barely) work. For example, requests are funneled to their respective urls.py, views are rendered, etc.

I have tried creating an empty new project with a new clean virtual environment with only Django 1.10 running on Python 3.5 but I cannot figure it out. (yes, I have `__init__.py` wherever neccesary)

What am I missing?

Comment: I created a similar project structure. `modules.app1` works for me.

Comment: @dunder you are correct; if I change "modules.app1.apps.App1Config" to "modules.app1", it will work. However the documentation expressly states that one should specify the dotted path to the AppConfig subclass

Comment: Got it! Learned something new today..

Comment: I agree that the `No module named 'app1'` error message is a bit confusing. In Django 1.11, it will say something like `Cannot import 'app1'. Check that 'modules.app1.apps.App1Config.name' is correct` (see [ticket #26618](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26618)).

Comment: That would be splendid. I would've search through AppConfig's documentation, but I had no idea the problem was inside it. Indeed, no module named 'app1' was precisely what was happening inside the config file, but I was expecting a more traditional ImportError

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well as updating `INSTALLED_APPS`, you need to update your `AppConfig.name` attributes to use the new path. For example:

```
class App1Config(AppConfig):
    name = 'modules.app1'
    ...
```